# Spring Data MongoDB configuration not working

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

My application.yml:
[image]

My application-divaddev.yml:
[image]

My build.gradle[image]

mongodb server is running and db created, but I get this response:[image]

Comment: They are there. See the second photo.

Comment: Write the uri without user and password like this `mongodb://localhost:27017/test`

Comment: Fixed by replacing the uri attribute with host: localhost, port: 27017

Comment: Found answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43070977/invalid-mongo-configuration-either-uri-or-host-port-credentials-must-be-specifi